# CodeIgniter index function not triggered even though the controller has been called

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

The short: The code sample below does not echo "Here I am!" It will not echo from the _construct function. It will echo if I move the echo statement above the class so I know CI is reaching this controller.

The backstory:

I've inherited a project done in CodeIgniter 2.1.2. I'm supposed to replicate an application to another directory with a different subdomain and pointing the database config to a different database. I have the database updated in the config. I've updated the base bath. I've set environment to development so I can get error messages. There are no errors.

```php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
if (!ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    date_default_timezone_set('my-time-zone');
}

class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mod_login');
        $this->load->helper('date');
    }

    function index() {
         echo "Here I am!"; //Nothing echos 
    }

   function logout{
   //logout function here.
   }
}
```

Any CodeIgniter fans here have an idea why?

Comment: Is this complete code of your controller?

Comment: There are other functions below it, but none that are being called. Also, I did not include CI_Controller because it's standard codeigniter and I have not modified it. This controller works fine in the original folder with the original application and I haven't had trouble adding functions before.

Comment: Debug line by line may be you can get problem like check in class echo some thing if fine then after construct function and so on.

Comment: I am not sure but may be your model or helper not load. Or just try without load model and helper it goes to index function or not.

Answer (score 2):

Your controller should be like this.

```
<?php    
    if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
        exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Login extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('mod_login');
            $this->load->helper('date');

        }

        public function index()
        {
            echo "Here I am!";
        }


     }
```

and controller name should be `loging.php`

and in `config/routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "login";/set default conntoller
```

### Extra Notes: (to remove `index.php` in URL)

in `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and `.htaccess` (place outside application folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You wrote cho instead of echo.

Comment: Yes. No luck. Again, to be clear, it's reaching this controller, CI is loading login.php because echo "Here I am" shows up if I put it above the class declaration. I have the .htaccess done already just like what you show.

Answer (score 1):

Class name of controller must be uppercase. From documentation:

> Note: Class names must start with an uppercase letter.

In other words, this is valid:

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

}
?>
```

This is **not** valid:

```
<?php
class blog extends CI_Controller {

}
?>
```

More: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#hello

Comment: Thanks. It didn't change or fix anything, but I don't want to perpetuate bad form.